# get all facebook likes without pagination in android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am using this code which returns only 25 pges I like .How can I get more ?

```
new Request(facebook.getSession(),
        "/me/likes",
        null,
        HttpMethod.GET,
        new Request.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {


        JSONArray   arr = null;
        GraphObject go  = response.getGraphObject();
        JSONObject  jso = go.getInnerJSONObject();
```

I tried :

```
/me/likes?limit=999"
```

This gives me null value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can´t just get all entries, the default limit is 25 per API call and you need to implement paging to get more results: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#paging

That means, if you want to get 100 entries, you need to use 4 API calls to get all of them. The call for the next batch of 25 entries is in the "next" value of the result, as you can read in the docs.

Without pagination there is no way to get all entries, unless there are only 25 ;) - you can try with a much smaller limit like 50 or 100 and see if it works, but there is definitely a max limit and it´s not very high.

Comment: then you may just need to use 25 and use paging after all. it´s the safest way anyway. it´s never good to rely on the limit parameter from my experience.